# R devtools: use local dependencies

Tags: r, dependencies, devtools, r-package, r-usethis

I want to add a local package dependency using R [devtools](https://devtools.r-lib.org/).
The [suggested way](https://r-pkgs.org/description.html) to add packages to the package DESCRIPTION file is one of the two functions `use_package()` and `use_dev_package()`, from the [usethis](https://usethis.r-lib.org/) package. The latter adds a dependency on an in-development package. The function help shows the following prototype:

```
use_dev_package(package, type = "Imports", remote = NULL)
```

where `remote` is

> a character string to specify the remote, e.g. ‘"gitlab::jimhester/covr"’, using any syntax           supported by the remotes package.

The [remotes vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/remotes/vignettes/dependencies.html) shows the following

```
# Local
Remotes: local::/pkgs/testthat
```

So the command should be along these lines:

```
use_dev_package(foopack, type = "Imports", remote = "local::<foopack>")
```

However, what should be the path to the `foopack`. An absolute one or relative to project dir? The root package directory or the R directory with the code, or perhaps the `foopack.tar.gz` build?
All attempts failed for me.

Needless to say that, beyond having the local dependency properly listed in the DESCRIPTION file, I need it to be seen by the devtools build & check functions.

## Edit

As regards `use_dev_package()`, I found a solution:
if I use `devtools::check()`, then the dependency appears in the search path, and `use_dev_package()` does not complain any more (see answer below).

However, it is still unclear to me what arguments should I use to make a *development* `check()` for the main package, in particular when the package has a vignette.

Ideally, I should be able to pass the check with local dependencies by passing  `cran = FALSE`, but this still gives
"Package required but not available".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that your main package depends on a local package `foopack".
To declare this dependency, first, install the dependency package from the local source:

```r
install.packages("path/to/foopack", repos = NULL)
```

Then add the local package dependency twice to the package `DESCRIPTION` file, in the `Imports` and in the `Remotes` sections, like below (adjust the `local::` path as needed):

```
Imports: 
    foopack,
Remotes: 
    local::../foopack
```

The  `DESCRIPTION` file editing can also be automated with the package `usethis`:

```r
usethis::use_dev_package("foopack", remote ="local::../foopack")
```

Now, `devtools::check()` gives no errors/warnings.
Of course, if checking for CRAN incoming feasibility with:

```r
devtools::check(incoming = TRUE, remote = TRUE)
```

one gets

```
Unknown, possibly misspelled, fields in DESCRIPTION:
  ‘Remotes’

Strong dependencies not in mainstream repositories:
  foopack
```

since `Remotes` is not an official description field and dependencies should be publicly available for submission on CRAN,